# VueJS - toggle background image of list item on hover

Tags: vue.js, mouseover

I'm relatively new to Vue and I'm wondering what's wrong with my component that my isHover variable (prop?) isn't working to change the background on mouseover.

```
<template>
  <div class="list-wrap" v-if="gridItems">
    <div
      class="list-itme"
      v-for="(item, index) in gridItems"
      :key="index"
      @click.stop="setCurrentLocation(location)"
    >
      <a
        @mouseover="mouseOver(index)"
        @mouseleave="mouseLeave(index)"
        :style="{
          background: isHover 
            ? `url(${item.location_image.thumbnails.large.url})`
            : `url(${item.location_image.thumbnails.largeHover.url})`
        }"
      >
        {{ item.location_name }}
        {{ isHover }}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "GridItems",
  computed: mapState(["filters", "GridItems"]),
  methods: {
    mouseOver(index) {
      this.item[index].isHover = true;
    },
    mouseLeave(index) {
      this.item[index].isHover = false;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isHover: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: can I clarify, you want to change the background image of the item if mouse hover on it?

Comment: Why would you do that with Vue when simple CSS is sufficient?

Comment: @stephenthomas because each background image is unique per item, pulled via API.

Comment: @evan yes, background image of item. The image is set via api in a loop, per item.

Comment: @StephenThomas You're right, I foolishly used colors in my example to try and keep it simple, but I just changed it to reflect the reatily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background: isHover 
        ? `url(${item.location_image.thumbnails.large.url})`
        : `url(${item.location_image.thumbnails.largeHover.url})`
```

The `isHover` above references the data property of the component.

Your `mouseOver()` and `mouseLeave()` methods are assigning a property also called `isHover` on `this.item[index]`. These are two completely different properties. Where are you getting `this.item` from? I don't see any props or it being declared as a data attribute.

**Edit**

You could have a `isHover` property on the gridItem. Therefore instead of passing `index` as an argument into the mouse event methods you can actually pass `item`. Then just set `item.isHover = true`. On the style binding you can just check against `item.isHover`.

Which means you don't need the "other" `isHover` data property on the component.

Comment: I am trying to modify a component I didn't build, so I'm not sure. I've just been trying different concatenations of things like a blind slug. The best I could do was get it so if I hover one item they all get the hover style. 

I'm not sure where to define `isHover` as a prop and give it a default value of false. Nor am I sure if I need the data() function in the export.

Comment: I have a relatively solid grasp of JS, but I didn't build the app and don't have time to clean up previous developer's code. It's a large, complex app and I'm just trying to make a few tweaks for the client without creating more work for myself by refactoring things that work, albeit maybe be ugly.

Comment: "refactoring things that work" .. but it's not working? Anyways - could you not just use CSS to handle the hover instead? You can add custom styles for components. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: This version is broken because I haven't gotten it to work. I posted the broken code, hoping someone would spot an obvious fix. The component works fine with a static bg image. And yes, for simple bg color changes I can use CSS... I foolishly used them in my example to try and simplify my code for posting. I changed it to reflect the reality. bg images like ``url(${item.location_image.thumbnails.large.url})``

Comment: Right that makes a lot more sense now! I edited my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206616/discussion-between-james-totty-and-kirk-ross).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider in your code, the `isHover` variable which is being used to change the background of your elements is a data property, but in your `mouseOver` and `mouseLeave` you are trying to change the `isHover` property from an element on an array called `item` which is not declared in the code you posted. Another thing to notice is that it is not necessary to return anything on your mouseOver and mouseLeave methods.

As I understand, the expected behavior of your code is to change the background color of the item you are hovering with your cursor. A couple of suggestions, you should use class binding instead of adding inline styles to your template elements, also you could pass the item instead of the index on your mouseover and mouseleave handlers. Another thing to mention is that I would only recommend doing this if for some reason you need the `isHover` property on your item for something else, otherwise you should just use CSS `:hover` to achieve this. I made a small demo so you can take a look on what you can do to make your code work: [codepen](https://codepen.io/davidalejandro/pen/PowXQyv)

**Edit**

To change the image when hovering over an item you should be using the `isHover` property of that particular item instead of the component's data property `isHover` which you are currently using to try to change the image url. I updated my [codepen](https://codepen.io/davidalejandro/pen/PowXQyv).

Comment: yes, I realize I can use CSS for non-dynamic styles... I foolishly used hex colors in my example to try and simplify my code for posting, but in truth, it's a dynamic bg image like ``url(${location.location_image.thumbnails.large.url})``. I changed it in my example to reflect the reality.

Comment: ok, you would have to use the isHover property from each item on the array, I updated my answer and codepen.

Comment: thank you for the codepen. It works there, but the only problem is the item object is coming from an API which I don't have access to, so I can't add the `isHover` prop to the object. Can I add the prop to each item during the loop render?

Comment: no problem, yes, you can add that property to the items on your mouseOver and mouseLeave handlers like this: `this.$set(item, 'isHover', true)` and `this.$set(item, 'isHover', false)`, you need to use `this.$set` in order to be reactive otherwise it won't update your component with that change, see codepen.

Comment: That works! I put it in my mouseOver() method. One console error though. `Property or method "isHover" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.` How do I set the initial isHover prop on each iteem as the page is first rendering?

Comment: Glad it helped! actually I think the console error is because of this line of code: `{{ isHover }}` right below `{{ item.location_name }}` or any other place where you are using the component's data property `isHover`, because it is no longer defined on your component's data, so you would need to replace `{{ isHover }}` to this: `{{ item.isHover ?  item.isHover : false }}`